# Conditional Data Type based on Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know that you can conditionally format the visual treatment of a cell using conditional formatting, but can I control the data type of a cell based on the value of another cell?

I'm building an expense sheet and I'd like to change a cell's data type to either `Accounting` or `Percentage` based on how they want the money to be taken from their paycheck.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this

You can use the [TEXT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-HP005209313.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) function to apply numeric formats. You have to use the numeric mask you want rather than a named value like `Percentage`. For example:

> =TEXT(B33, "0%")

Or you could use VBA. Using the [NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224873(v=office.11).aspx) property you could dynamically set the format based on another cell. For example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17").NumberFormat = "General"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C"). _
    NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
```

Comment: @Jon Updated answer to include TEXT function. I seem to forget that one exists.